# How Child class constructor set the parent class attribute

Tags: python

In python, how can I setup the Parent class attributes in Child Class constructor.

My Parent class has 2 attributes which set in its constructor:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "abc"
        self.attribute2 = 1

    def afunction():
         # something to print attributes"
         print(self.attribute1 + self.attribute2)
```

In my child class, in the construtor, I try to override the `attribute1`, `attribute2` by

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super.attribute1 = "def"
        super.attribute2 = 3
```

But I get error `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'super'`

What i want to when x = Child()  x.afunction(), I should see it print "def3"

Comment: just do `self.attribute1 = whatever`. The child inherits the method and attributes from the parent. And you might do `super().__init__()` to initialize them to 'abc' and 1.

Comment: Instance attributes don't really belong to any one class. `attribute1` and `attribute2`  don't belong to `Parent`, though they are set on the instance by a method defined by `Parent.` (This is one of the reasons that multiple inheritance is less of an issue in Python than it is in C++.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the inheritance right way. Your parent class already have 2 attributes, but you are not exposing them to be parametrized to be instantiated by clients as well as subclasses. You could do this as follows:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, attribute1="abc", attribute2=1):
        self.attribute1 = attribute1
        self.attribute2 = attribute2

    def afunction(self):
        print(self.attribute1 + str(self.attribute2))


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, attribute1="def", attribute2=3):
        super().__init__(attribute1, attribute2)


Child().afunction()
Child("test", 3).afunction()
```

This way you are allowing clients to provide value for your attributes, not reassign them in child. Also exposing attributes to the clients so they can pass them if they need else it uses the default value

Comment: Duplicating the arguments in `Parent.__init__` and `Child.__init__` is not recommended. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for details, but in brief: `Child.__init__` should simply accept arbitrary keyword arguments that it will pass on to `super().__init__`, so that the appropriate upstream class can handle them. If that's the *only* thing `Child.__init__` would do, it doesn't even need to be defined.

Comment: @chepner You said it correct, totally agree. I just wanted to keep it in the context of question though.  When we want to add more child level attributes, that could be done by this approach.

Answer (score 1):

To build up on my comment:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "abc"
        self.attribute2 = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "def"
        self.attribute2 = 3

c = Child()
```

In this case, the child is initialize. In the initialization 2 attributes are created with the value `def` and `3`. The attributes are never initialized with the values from the parent class.

Alternatively:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute1 = "abc"
        self.attribute2 = 1

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.attribute1 = "def"
        self.attribute2 = 3

c = Child()
```

This time, the attributes are first initialized during the `super()` call by calling the function `__init__()` from the parent class. And then they are overridden.

Which one you prefer depends on your application, but either way, you can create the attribute directly in the child class as they don't belong to one specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Got It In Place Of `Super()` try Acccesing It With `Parent.`
And Then Print It I Definitely Say You Will Get Your Answer :'def'

Comment: `Parent` is not a keyword, and setting a class attribute is not the same as setting an instance attribute.

Comment: @chepner For the simplicity  i said Keyword but i mean to say is just replace `Super` with `Parent` and then just show me a case where it doesn't work or should i  post proof of it